Azure Devops remove user from Project Collection Administrators
I'm trying to remove a user from Project Collection Administrators but keep getting this error

Collection owner cannot be removed from 'Project Collection Administrators' group

Not sure where else I need to remove the user from, I checked all projects and they are not admin on any of them.
Thank you,


Collection owner cannot be removed from 'Project Collection Administrators' group

It seems you're trying to remove the user set as organization owner, which is the highest level of administrative privilege within an organization.
Try this:

Change the organization owner to another user
Remove the user you want

